# error with if else conditions

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
main()
{
int gans[20]={43575, 87565, 33256, 92394, 12839, 30956, 23595, 21983, 10223, 65805, 000001, 32998, 47899, 56688, 55442, 63363, 65897, 12758, 32546, 42536};    
double premios[]={500.00, 700.00, 800.00, 900.00, 1200.00, 1500.00, 1800.00, 2000.00, 2100.00, 2300.00, 2800.00, 3000.00, 3200.00, 3500.00, 4000.00, 10000.00, 100000.00, 200000.00, 500000.00, 1000000 };    

int bolcliente, i;       
cout<<"Introduzca su numero de boleto: ";
cin>>bolcliente;


if(bolcliente==gans[0]) {cout<<"Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<<premios[0]<<" pesos";} 
 if(bolcliente==gans[1]) {cout<<"Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<<premios[1]<<" pesos";} 
  if(bolcliente==gans[2]) {cout<<"Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<<premios[2]<<" pesos";} 
   if(bolcliente==gans[3]) {cout<<"Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<<premios[3]<<" pesos";}
    if(bolcliente==gans[4]) {cout<<"Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<<premios[4]<<" pesos";}
     if(bolcliente==gans[5]) {cout<<"Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<<premios[5]<<" pesos";}
      if(bolcliente==gans[6]) {cout<<"Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<<premios[6]<<" pesos";}
       if(bolcliente==gans[7]) {cout<<"Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<<premios[7]<<" pesos";}
        if(bolcliente==gans[8]) {cout<<"Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<<premios[8]<<" pesos";}
         if(bolcliente==gans[9]) {cout<<"Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<<premios[9]<<" pesos";}
          if(bolcliente==gans[10]) {cout<<"Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<<premios[10]<<" pesos";}
           if(bolcliente==gans[11]) {cout<<"Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<<premios[11]<<" pesos";}
            if(bolcliente==gans[12]) {cout<<"Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<<premios[12]<<" pesos";}
             if(bolcliente==gans[13]) {cout<<"Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<<premios[13]<<" pesos";}
              if(bolcliente==gans[14]) {cout<<"Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<<premios[14]<<" pesos";}
               if(bolcliente==gans[15]) {cout<<"Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<<premios[15]<<" pesos";}
                if(bolcliente==gans[16]) {cout<<"Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<<premios[16]<<" pesos";}
                 if(bolcliente==gans[17]) {cout<<"Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<<premios[17]<<" pesos";}
                  if(bolcliente==gans[18]) {cout<<"Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<<premios[18]<<" pesos";}
                   if(bolcliente==gans[19]) {cout<<"Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<<premios[19]<<" pesos";}
                    else{cout<<"Lo sentimos, no haz ganado premio alguno, suerte para la proxima"<<endl;            }     



system("pause");
}
```

Hi, can you help me with the code? This program is in spanish as you can see, it asks for the user to enter the number of his lotto ticket and if he is a winner (any number from the array gans) then a message is printed, if he didnt win a message should be printed with another message,  and it does, but if he is a winner the else condition is also printed even if he won, can you help me with this error?

Comment: You can pretty much replace all of that giant block with one `std::find` call and an if-else.

Comment: i still dont know a lot of functions, thats why im making it as i can, but thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if there were 50 numbers instead of 20?  How about 100 numbers instead of 20?  Would you write all of those if statements 100 times?  How about 1000 items?  You will tire yourself out with the way you wrote the code.

Think of it this way -- either you found an item, or you haven't found an item.  Thus there are two scenarios.  Going on that information, think how to rewrite your if/else using that in mind.

Here is the same code with a much saner approach (and it will solve your problem):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int gans[]={43575, 87565, 33256, 92394, 12839, 30956, 23595, 21983, 10223, 65805, 
                000001, 32998, 47899, 56688, 55442, 63363, 65897, 12758, 32546, 
                42536};    
    const int numGans = sizeof(gans) / sizeof(gans[0]);
    double premios[]={500.00, 700.00, 800.00, 900.00, 1200.00, 1500.00, 1800.00, 
                      2000.00, 2100.00, 2300.00, 2800.00, 3000.00, 3200.00, 3500.00, 
                      4000.00, 10000.00, 100000.00, 200000.00, 500000.00, 1000000 
                     };    
    int bolcliente, i;       
    cout<<"Introduzca su numero de boleto: ";
    cin>>bolcliente;
    int* pGans = std::find(gans, gans + numGans, bolcliente);

    // found an item
    if ( pGans != gans + numGans )
    {
        int whichOne = std::distance(gans, pGans);
        cout << "Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: "<< 
                premios[whichOne]<<" pesos";
    }
    else 
    // didn't find the item
        cout<<"Lo sentimos, no haz ganado premio alguno, suerte para la proxima"
           << endl;
}
```

Note the use of find().  If the item is not found, the returned pointer will point to one past the last valid item.

If the item is found, then to get the one that was found, we call std::distance() to compute the number of items between the first item and the found item.

The bottom line is this -- if you see yourself writing the same thing over and over again (in your case 20 times), with the only difference being a variable or a number here or the pattern of code is similar, then it's time to look at the code and see if it can be rewritten in a shorter way.

Even if you couldn't think of using algorithms, a for() loop could have been written that loops until the right number is found.

```
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < numGans && !found; ++i)
{
    if (gans[i] == bolcliente)
    {
      cout << "Felicidades, haz ganado el premio de: " << premios[i] << " pesos";
      found = true;
    }
}
if ( !found )
    cout << "Lo sentimos, no haz ganado premio alguno, suerte para la proxima" << endl;
```

Comment: qwow, thats a lot of work from you i guess, but im still in 2nd semester and i dont know a lot of functions, but thanks, ill try to understand your code

Comment: Look at the second example with the for loop.  You should know what a for() loop if it's your second semester.  It should be simple enough to understand.  If you say it out loud what is in that loop, it should make sense.

Comment: lol of course that i know what a loop is, but i dont know some other functios like  the sizeof or the std::fin, im reading it to try to understand them but thats why my code is really simple, because thats the way i can do it...
so, do you know how can i fix my problem in my own code?

Comment: The second example using the simple for loop is simple.  If you know what a for loop is and you know what an array is, then I don't see what the issue is with understanding the code.  The `sizeof(array)/ sizeof(array[0])` gives me the number of elements in the array without hardcoding the value, that's all.  Given that I've just told you what the sizeof()'s are doing, can you now understand the loop?

Comment: Also, learn what if-then-else does, but do not use it as you're using it now.  That's the point I'm making.  A good programmer finds repeated patterns in their code and always tries to find a way to fix the issue.  You shouldn't automatically accept the "easy solution", because that easy solution becomes unmaintainable in the long run.  Similar to sweeping junk under a carpet, and then saying you've cleaned the room.  Yes, the room is "clean", but how much more junk can you sweep under the carpet?

Answer (score 1):

That `else` refers only to the `if` directly above it. Let's say `bolcliente==gans[10]`. The program checks each condition. When it gets to `bolcliente==gans[19]`, it discovers that no, it isn't equal, so it runs the `cout<<"Lo sentimos, ... "`.

Comment: Oh i get it, but when i add an else after every if it shows as many "else" as i have, in this case, it prints 19 times the cout<<"lo sentimos..."  so how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `else` before every `if` except the first one.